# Sharepoint-Designer 2010 "Remember-Mail-Workflow"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I got an pretty simple problem, but cant get over it.
I got a task in my Sharepoint 2010 and you have to confirm a transaction.. thats working alright.

Each task involves 3 people and they are sorted in a list with the headers :

- Assigned to
- Title
- Status
- Result

So I had the idea to make a workflow to remind ppl on the task, when the status in NOT "completed".
This also seem to work, but the problem is when I tell him to get the Description of the "Assigned to" part of the List he always takes the first one. So I have no chance to check the other ones in the list.

I would be really happy if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2010 has no built-in capability for looping through multiple List Items that meet a criteria.  Most people will say you cannot achieve what you want to do with that version of SharePoint.

However, John Hipplito had a great post several years ago that shows how you can emulate it by creating a separate "Loop through Tasks" list, and you can use one workflow to add items to the second list as needed, and put your desired "for each" actions (in your case, your email reminder) in a separate workflow on the second list.  The process is much to long and detailed to list here, so I suggest you read his post at https://www.rbaconsulting.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-loop-through-multiple-list-items-without-code-using-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow/.

Since that blog post is already nearly five years old, and you never know when old blogs may be taken down, I will also post a link here to the wayback machine's archive of that blog post:  https://web.archive.org/web/20200215193135/https://www.rbaconsulting.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-loop-through-multiple-list-items-without-code-using-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow/